# matplotlib 'bar' vs 'barh' plots. Problem with barh

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've just noticed something strange and was wondering if someone could explain what's going on?

I have a dictionary i'm plotting a horizontal and vertical bar charts from.

```
plt.bar(food.keys(), food.values()) #works fine, but:
plt.barh(food.keys(), food.values() #gives "unhashable type: 'dict_keys'" error.
```

if dictionary is unhashable, why does it let me plot a normal bar graph? Is this just a quirk of the barh function or am I doing something wrong?

Here's my test dataset:

```
food = {'blueberries':2, 'pizza':3.50, 'apples':0.50}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answer is of course correct in how to solve the problem - simply convert to a list. The reason why it doesn't work in the first place involves digging into the matplotlib source code.

`bar` and `barh` do both call `matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar` under the hood. When you plot a `bar`, `x` is the x position of the bars and `height` is the y value.

However, calling a `barh`, the y values (i.e. `['blueberries', 'pizza', 'apples']`) is actually set to the argument `bottom` and the length of the bars is given by `width`.

The following line is called within the source code

```
func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
```

Where `sanitize_sequence` is:

```
def sanitize_sequence(data):
    """
    Convert dictview objects to list. Other inputs are returned unchanged.
    """
    return (list(data) if isinstance(data, collections.abc.MappingView)
            else data)
```

The problem is that the argument `bottom` is a kwarg, and is therefore *not* passed to `sanitize_sequence` and is never converted to a list. Whereas in a normal `bar`, `x` is converted to a list by `sanitize_sequence`

So the issue is with how `barh` is implemented under the hood.

Comment: I thought it was an 'under the hood' thing. Thanks for confirming! My work around was to put it into a link then to plot it.

Answer (score 7):

Nice MWE. Looks like you ran into a subtle python 2 to python 3 conversion bug.

Under python 2, `dict.keys()` (etc.) used to return lists of values. Under python 3, `dict.keys()` returns a view of the data corresponding to the keys. This view is not hashable (I think in principle, it would be; however, that behaviour is not implemented (yet)). Coercing your key view to a list circumvents the issue:

```
plt.barh(list(food.keys()), food.values())
```

#### Edit

The real question is why `plt.bar` works, as both, `plt.bar` and `plt.barh` call `matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar` under the hood.
[The definition of `barh`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/8bbff6dca5caa4163436df126c2531f60cc95ee1/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2533) is literally:

```
def barh(self, y, width, height=0.8, left=None, *, align="center",
         **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('orientation', 'horizontal')
    patches = self.bar(x=left, height=height, width=width, bottom=y,
                       align=align, **kwargs)
    return patches
```